# SQL 2008 Multiple instances on Windows Server 2008 - Firewall settings?

Tags: sql-server, firewall

We're just in the process of moving to Windows Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008, so I'm not sure if this is a firewall issue.  If I disable the firewall though, all is fine...

Basically, I cannot connect to my SQL named instances, although the default instances are fine.

What ports should I have open on the Firewall to allow access to all instances?  At the moment I have specific ports listed, 1433 and 1434 for SQL Server and Browser respectively.

Should I be pointing at my d:\mssql*\binn\sqlsrvr.exe programs instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its best to use SQL configuration manager to set the ports explicity and then open these in the firewall.

Make sure that UDP 1434 is open for the browser service.

Comment: Seems like I had a couple of issues.
I had put the browser as TCP instead of UDP - changing that to UDP fixed the browsing.  I've then put in an additional firewall rule pointing to the relevent sqlsrvr.exe and it looks like I can connect now.  I'm a bit hesitant to use specific ports if I can help it.

Comment: Doesn't the browser service deal with the dynamic ports of the named instances?  If they were explicitly set, one would think the service would not be needed.

Comment: it deals with port of instance.  dynamic or not... so without it you could need to specify port number in connection string....

server\instance, port

Comment: Yeah, I think the problem I had was that because the browser service was being blocked, nothing else could get through on the dynamic ports (or not find them anyway)
As soon as the Browser started up, the rest just worked.  (I just made the exe accessible in the firewall)